# Slideshow in Javascript when the image changed is the background image

Tags: javascript, css, slideshow

The client wants to have a simple slideshow with a little twist: he wants the menu to be on top of the image being changed.

what would be the way to achieve this using css and javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a background image, just put the menu in a division and position it absolutely on the top of the image somewhere. You can't resize background images and if the images are bigger than the client's visible area they will be cut off.

Comment: Not until most browsers support CSS3 background image resizing, that is. :(

Answer (score 0):

As you normally do. The order of the image and menu is important. If the menu is after the image then you are ok. If you can't/won't change the order then you'll have to use the css z-index property.